# Issue sending keys, values to django Q()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to filter some IDs using a django query and trying to do it efficiently, I want to get the same result I got from a less efficient function I created before, but I am getting an issue with the dictionary key using Q

```
from tmd import models
from django.db.models import Q

category = {
    "utility": models.Account.UTILITY, 
    "system": models.Account.SYSTEM
    }
country = {
    "United States": models.Country.objects.get(name='USA'),
    "Canada": models.Country.objects.get(name='CA'),
}


def get_a(stage=None, **kwargs):
        base_args =[]
        base_args.append(Q(stage__in=stage))
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            base_args.append(Q(key= value))
                    
        a_ids = models.Account.objects.filter(*base_args).values_list('id', flat=True)
        print("Number of a_ids: {}".format(a_ids.count()))
        return a_ids
```

input:

```
a_ids = get_a(country=country["USA"], category=category["utility"])
```

The issue is located exactly in this line:

```
base_args.append(Q(key= value))
```

If I can make an input that changes the key for every iteration, this will be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
base_args.append( Q( **{ key: value} ))
```

I'm wondering whether you need Q. The same way of handling dynamic kwargs can get you to

```
a_ids = models.Account.objects.filter( stage__in=stage
           )                  .filter( **kwargs 
           )
```

which is and-logic of the various keyword=value filter terms

Comment: Thank you, it worked fantastically. Can you give me an example of the **kwargs to input in your second answer?

Comment: If I followed your code right, yours! Otherwise, if `kwargs` was `{'a':5, 'baz':'foo'}`, then `.filter( **kwargs)` is the same as `.filter( a=5, baz='foo')` (which employs and logic, filtering objects with both a=5 AND baz='foo'.)